# Rusqlite: securely inserting multiple rows

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I want to insert multiple rows into a sqlite database using Rusqlite. The values may contain single quote characters.

This simple way of inserting multiple rows works as long as none of the values contains a single quote character:

```
insert into table (field1, field2, field3) 
values ('Value a1', 'Value a2', 'Value a3'), 
       ('Value b1', 'Value b2', 'Value b3')
```

But as soon as one value contains a single quote, the insert fails (of course).

When inserting a single row, you can securely do it this way:

```
let sSQL: String  = format!("insert into table(field1, field2, field3) values(?1, ?2, ?3)");
let mut stmt = conn.prepare (&sSQL)?;

stmt.execute([&sValue1, &sValue2, &sValue3]);
```

My question: what is the best way of securely inserting multiple rows, which may also contain single quotes?

Comment: Same question but the answer doesn't address how to escape the quotes: [Rusqlite insert multiple rows](/q/65789938/2189130).

Answer (score 1):

As the example in the [documentation for `Connection::prepare` says](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Transaction.html#method.prepare), you can just call `Statement::execute` multiple times to achieve the desired effect:

```
let sSQL: String  = format!("insert into table(field1, field2, field3) values(?1, ?2, ?3)");
let mut stmt = conn.prepare (&sSQL)?;

stmt.execute([&sValue11, &sValue12, &sValue13])?;
stmt.execute([&sValue21, &sValue22, &sValue23])?;
```

(Also, don't forget to handle the `Result`s of `execute` calls too!)

Comment: If you know that you're always inserting two rows at that location you can also have 6 placeholders with the original query. It's a single statements, drivers don't make a difference. Also why are you format-ing a static query?

Comment: @FZs: Isn't that much less performant than inserting all values with a single call?

Comment: @Masklinn: No, unfortunately the number of rows to insert is dynamic. Is there a way to build the params for stmt.execute dynamically?

Comment: That is error prone, and unless you have profiled the code and know that this specifically is a hotspot, it's unlikely to be useful (prepared statements are generally a way to optimise repeated queries). You would probably be better off wrapping your insertions in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

> My question: what is the best way of securely inserting multiple rows, which may also contain single quotes?

If you know that you always need to insert 2 rows, you can just expand the existing version:

```rust
let sSQL = "insert into table(field1, field2, field3) values (?1, ?2, ?3), (?4, ?5, ?6)";
let mut stmt = conn.prepare (&sSQL)?;

stmt.execute((&v1, &v2, &v3, &v4, &v5, &v6));
```

Otherwise it's as FZs indicates, you can `execute` a prepared statement multiple times. In fact that's rather the point of using a prepared statement, otherwise you could just use [`Connection::execute`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Transaction.html#method.execute).

> This simple way of inserting multiple rows works as long as none of the values contains a single quote character:

Note that this should generally be considered broken if the query is not a static string. Even if you think you know that all the dynamic data you're injecting is safe, it's an unnecessary risk.

> When inserting a single row, you can securely do it this way:

Note that numbering the placeholders is not a requirement, `?` will work just as well and will work as if they were numbered sequentially. The main advantages of explicit numbering are:

- Keeping track on large queries with many parameters.
- Using the same parameter multiple times.
- If for some reason you need to alter the order of parameters in the query without being able to change that of the parameters themselves.

But in those situations (possibly aside from the last) you may want to use [named parameters](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/macro.named_params.html) instead anyway.

I would also recommend using a *tuple* of parameters in all cases but sending a single parameter: an array or slice will not allow different parameter types, so might as well consistently use tuples.